# Categorized and linked WordPress users

Tags: wordpress, admin, categories, roles

I will develop a blog in WordPress with an post contribution system (`contributor`) grouping several pole.
These contributors must be attached to a pole (they will write posts related to their pole).
I would like to add `editor` for each pole so that they can manage the posts of the contributors of its pole only.

The idea would be to be able to categorize users (Pole A, Pole B, Pole C, ...).
Is it possible to do this (with code or a plugin)? I would like to avoid using a multisite.

Of course, there will be admin who will have control over all post.

Here is the principle schematized:
[image]

Thank you in advance for your help.